# Do we stop Depth First Search if the goal is found in the neighbour nodes?

Tags: graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

Just trying to get my head around this algorithm. Consider a small tree with a root node and 3 children. With A being root and B C D being it's children and then root B having child E. If the goal was D, do we stop as soon as the root is expanded or do we keep traversing down to E, come back up, then try and expand C before we go to D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check every leaf in the tree taking all the paths as deep as possible. So if you have an order on **B C D** (i.e. you got them in this order from enumerating A's leaves) you'll go **A B E** first, then **C** and the last will be **D**.

This is usually done by having a special structure to store unattended leaves.

Comment: The simplest implementation of DFS is just a recursive function. BFS is trickier and requires clever storage.

Comment: Yeah, in this case you store data on stack basically q: